# Считывание из файла в режиме Онлайн

Tags: файлы, java

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать на java следующий проект.  Есть текстовый файл, в нем что то записано. Мне надо его считать и вывести на экран. Но в чем проблема! Надо реализовать так чтобы, эта прога была включена до тех пор пока ее не закроет пользователь. Если в текстовый файл добавили что-то новое и сохранили, то это сразу должно вылезти на экран программы. Если ничего не добавили, то программа работает дальше.
Я не прошу реализации всего задания, подскажите, как реализовать последние 3 предложения.

Comment: самое банальное - по таймеру проверяйте дату последней модификации, если она поменялась - перезагружайте файл. Это если без привязки к какой-либо операционной системе.

Но если к примеру задача для Линукс, то там можно использовать [inotify](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) - будут присылаться уведомления, если файл поменялся.

Comment: Я бы не хотел заново загружать файл,а чтобы после добавления и сохранения, в окне показывало что добавилось

Comment: это Вам нужно делать diff. Но загружать файл все равно придется. Конечно, в некоторых осях есть апи, которые говорят, какая часть файла поменялась, но всему есть предел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, все можно.
Есть такая штука `java.nio.file.WatchService` - которая мониторит состояние файла
Вот дока: [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Получается эвентовая модель

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, смысл эвентовой модели.

Comment: эм...что-то случается, формируется эвент, Вы обрабатываете этот эвент, делаете какие-то действия. Т.е. вы не гоняете в потоке цикл, с проверкой условия, а подписываетесь на определенное событие.
ЗЫ: до исходников этой штуковины я пока не добрался, как она внутри работает не скажу (может и цикл гоняет). Но работает вполне удобно

Comment: Да, по русски скажи - событийная модель. По событию поднимается некий слушатель/listener, в котором что-то можно сделать

Comment: ну да точняк...по русски, не "HiTech", а "ВысТех", не "Listener", а "слуахч" =)..шутю..сам не люблю птичий язык, но как в обиходе, так и на словах)